# Use of NOT EXIST in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Someone help me about this code:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
               FROM AgencyEmailAddress 
               WHERE AgencyID = @agencyID 
                AND EmailAddress = @emailAddress
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO AgencyEmailAddress(AgencyID, EmailAddress) 
    VALUES(@agencyID, @emailAddress) 
END
```

It throws an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.

Comment: thanks for edit, can you help me for this error SIr?

Answer (score 2):

Syntax is

```
If not exists(some statement) 
Begin
--do some work
END
```

So your statement goes like this

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM AgencyEmailAddress WHERE AgencyID = @agencyID and EmailAddress = @emailAddress)
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO AgencyEmailAddress(AgencyID, EmailAddress) 
VALUES(@agencyID, @emailAddress) 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a couple of closing parentheses just before the `BEGIN`.

Try this:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM AgencyEmailAddress WHERE AgencyID = @agencyID and EmailAddress = @emailAddress))
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO AgencyEmailAddress(AgencyID, EmailAddress) 
VALUES(@agencyID, @emailAddress) 
END
```